# localStorage - save input value after Spotify Access Token refresh

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm making a ReactJS app and I'm trying to *save* the search input value after my Spotify API refreshes and gets the access token. For example, here are the steps:

1. Learner searches a term
2. The Spotify API goes fetches the access token and *refreshes* the page

From step two, I would like the search term to be still *inside* the search input field (after the refresh).

Here is my attempt:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        term: ''
    };

    ...

    document.getElementById('search-input') = window.localStorage['term'];
}
```

...

```
search(){
    this.props.onSearch(this.state.term);
    window.localStorage['term'] = this.state.term;
}
```

...

```
    render(){
        return (
                <div>
                  <input id="search-input" onChange={this.handleTermChange} autoFocus/>
                  <a id="search" onClick={this.search}>SEARCH</a>
                </div>
        );
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than setting and getting your localStorage value with `window.localStorage['term']`, you'll want to use the built-in `get` and `set` methods.

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value)
localStorage.getItem(key)
```

[Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#Example) an example from MDN.